# Why does this series define $\tan (z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, trigonometric-series

According to Wolfram Alpha, $\tan(z) = i\left(1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^kq^{2k}\right): q=e^{iz}$. It seemed to make sense when I first looked at it, but upon closer examination, I am convinced that this is not the case. Just look, for $\tan(\frac{\pi}4)=$
$$
e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)\\
i\left(1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^ke^{\frac{\pi ki}2}\right)\\
i\left(1\quad\underset{\text{periodic, cancels}}{\underbrace{-2e^{\frac{i\pi}2}+2e^{i\pi}-2e^{\frac{3i\pi}2}+2e^{2i\pi}\dots}}\right)\\
i\left(1\quad\underset{\text{periodic, cancels}}{\underbrace{-2i\boxed{-2}+2i+\boxed{2}\dots}}\right)\\
\downarrow\\
\tan\left(\frac\pi4\right)=i
$$
Clearly, this is a contradiction. However, I don't know where I went wrong... can someone point out where I did? Or is Wolfram Alpha just wrong?

*EDIT: I know this may seem as if I am assuming that there is a "final value" to a periodic sum, to say that it cancels, but it is also assuming that there is a final value to assume that the sum equates to anything at all. So what gives?*

Comment: The sum only converges (in the ordinary sense) when $z$ is in the upper half plane.  When $z$ is real, then $|q| = 1$ so the terms of the sum do not have limit 0, so sum doesn't converge.

Comment: and $i\tan z = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}} = \frac{e^{2ix}-1}{e^{2ix}+1} = \frac{q^2-1}{q^2+1} = (q^2-1) \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k q^{2k} = 1+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k q^{2k}$ for $|q| < 1$

Comment: @user1952009 actually the last member should be $-1$ times what is rendered above.  As $q$ approaches $0$ the preceding quantity approaches $-1$ not $+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Euler sum of $-2i-2+2i+2...$ is not $0$.  It is $-1-i$.  Put that in for the periodic sum and get $\tan(\pi/4)=1$ as expected.

I used the Euler sum above.  When $z$ is real we find this necessary, as the series does not strictly converge.  The Euler sum, where it exists, gives the tangent as a limiting value from arguments in the upper half plane where the series really does converge.